# Execute javascript function when element gets loaded

Tags: javascript, html

How I could execute javascript function when HTML element appears from AJAX. This is my idea, but it does not execute blink:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Node JS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html , body {
        font: normal 0.9em arial , helvetica;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var a=0;
    function blinkColor()
    {
      document.getElementById("red").style.background="red"
      setTimeout("setblinkColor()",500)
    }

    function setblinkColor()
    {
      a++;
      if (a<4){
      document.getElementById("red").style.background=""
      setTimeout("blinkColor()",500)
      }
      else{
      document.getElementById("red").style.background=""
      }
    }



     $(document).ready(function() {
      var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:3000');
      var out = "";
      socket.on('populate', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    if(obj['Ping'] == "FALSE"){
          out += "<li id='red'><font color='red'>"+obj.Vardas+" is down..."+obj.Data+"</font></li>";
    }
    else{
          out += "<li><font color='green'>"+obj.Vardas+" is up......."+obj.Data+"</font></li>"; 
    }
        });
    $('#database').html(out);
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "blinkColor()">
  <div style="float:right; overflow:scroll; height: 400px; width: 30%">
    <ul id ='database'></ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In loads array from socket, takes values and generate html list object. List gets generated, but I want that when element appears it blinks for few seconds. I need to call blinColor() function for that.

I added test.html to call elements with getElementsByClass but it does not work... Seems to be very simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var a=0;
    function blinkColor()
    {
      document.getElementsByClass('blink').style.background="red"
      setTimeout("setblinkColor()",500)
    }

    function setblinkColor()
    {
      a++;
      if (a<4){
      document.getElementsByClass('blink').style.background=""
      setTimeout("blinkColor()",500)
      }
      else{
      document.getElementsByClass('blink').style.background=""
      }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="blinkColor()">
<h1 class="blink">Hello World!</h1>
<p class="blink">Hello World!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not calling `blinkColor` from the ajax code?

Comment: Never pass strings into `setTimeout`, but functions.

Comment: I added load function, but only first element blinks, even if new element with same id pops, first one blinks... Now its like this:  $('#database').html(out).load(blinkColor());

Comment: "*with same id*" - did I understand that right? Ids need to be unique, and `getElementById` does of course select only one element.

Comment: Yeas, that is the issue... I generate many elements with "same id" to call same function. Is there a way to call 'blinkColor' for many objects ?

Comment: Why not use a class? Or just pass the recently added element (without any identificator) as an argument to the animation function?

Comment: I added test script with class, but it does not work...

Comment: getElement *s* ByClassName does return a `NodeList`, which you will have to iterate.

Comment: I know that you do not need a function to iterate a NodeList - use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code:

- getElementsByClass should be getElementsByClassName
- background should be backgroundColor

Sample code:

```
var blinks=document.getElementsByClassName('blink');
for (var i=0,blinksCount=blinks.length;i<blinksCount;i++) {
    blinks[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Comment: @sauletasmiestas could you update your question with your new code? I have added a sample to my answer.